# How to connect ML model which is made in python to react native app

Tags: python, react-native, deployment

i made a one ML model in python now i want to  use this model in react native app means that frontend will be based on react native and model is made on python,how can i connect both thing with each other

Answer (score 1):

There is very little information in your post. What is the ML algo, what ML lib are you using, what framework, how this will be served?

Generally speaking you could use [TensorflowJS](https://www.tensorflow.org/js), if you want your model to do the inference **client-side**. (Depending on what ML lib you used, you can even [convert your model](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api) directly to TensorflowJS)

If your model doesn't have to run on client-side, you can have your app send the data to the back-end (maybe through GET/POST) do the inference and return the prediction to the front-end.

Again, this is very broadly, since you provided no specifics.

Answer (score 1):

create a REST Api in flask/django to deploy your model on server.create end points for separate functions.Then call those end points in your react native app.Thats how it works.

Comment: can you provide some resources where I could get help ?

Comment: @Shagunarora please follow this links                                                                      1- https://towardsdatascience.com/deploying-a-machine-learning-model-as-a-rest-api-4a03b865c166

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the CoreMl library for react native application if you are developing for IOS platform else creating a restAPI is a good option. (Though some developers say that latency is an issue but it also depends on what kind of model and dataset you are using ).